# Auto format keywords with pdflatex

Tags: latex, pdflatex, autoformatting

How can I auto format (bold, italic, ...) specific keywords in a latex document, without the use of commands for every keyword. Is there a solution for **pdflatex**?

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually edit every keyword. For example, you want to make the word `computer` in **Bold**, in the following sentence:

"The `\textbf{computer}` is from 20th century."

The command for italics, is: `\textit{computer}`

But it won't work for the whole file!

Hope it helps!

Comment: ...not really, as the OP requested "without the use of commands for every keyword"...